# Store thumb image to specific directory in paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Here is the code

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                        :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
                        :url  => "/images/:id/:filename",
                        :styles => { :small => "300x168>", :large => "1000x560>" }
```

Here is my console log

```
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-1gg7ekt.png'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x168>" '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm20150617-13080-8q41x9'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm20150617-13080-8q41x9'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "1000x560>" '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm20150617-13080-q57vxf'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-197v1bm20150617-13080-q57vxf'
Command :: PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.9/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/2251fc5821941d6bd28b2ee3cb25bf7620150617-13080-1o3we23.png'
```

I need to store small,large and original image to my project public directory but it store only the original

Comment: `@user.image.url(:small)` what it is return?

Comment: you can try this `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User`

Answer (score 0):

Check that your image magick installed correctly or not as resizing is depends on image magick.

to refresh all of your defined styles in one go (:thumb, :small, :medium from the above example)

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Modelname
```

and to refresh only missing styles:
a list of styles will be defined or updated in a file “/public/system/paperclip_attachments.yml”

```
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
```

Additionally, if you want to only reprocess a single style you may do so like:

```
users_to_reprocess.each do |user|
  user.image.reprocess! :small
end
```

Comment: I try this but still I have issue with , I added console log as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:styles` of `paperclip` gem in your model. Like,

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "300x300>",
    :large =>   "400x400>" }
```

And your photo url is going to be as follows : `/public/photos/(event#)/(size_name)/image_name`

And you have to install `ImageMagick` and `rb-magick` ports to get this going.

For more details you can refer this links [Upload Image using Paperclip gem](http://burm.net/2008/10/07/the-ruby-on-rails-paperclip-plugin-tutorial-easy-image-attachments/)